# Lookup [HOST]: no such host error in Go

Tags: linux, http, networking, concurrency, go

I have this test program which will fetch url parallel, but when I increase the parallel number to about 1040, I start to get `lookup www.httpbin.org: no such host` error.

After some Google, I found others say that not close the response will cause the problem, but I do close that with `res.Body.Close()`.

What's the problem here? thanks very much.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func get(url string) ([]byte, error) {

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    res, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    } 

    bytes, read_err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println(bytes)

    return bytes, read_err
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 1040; i++ {
        go get(fmt.Sprintf("http://www.httpbin.org/get?a=%d", i))
    }
}
```

Comment: I upvoted both dystroy and simonmenke's answers because they are both right. They just approached the problem from two different angles. The issue is you are hitting the FD limit by opening over 1000 connections to the host simultaneously. Dystroy's answer is to use less FDs by making less concurrent connections and simonmenke's is to increase the FD limit. For your specific case, I recommend Dystroy's answer. For someone else running into this same problem, it may make more sense to use simonmenke's.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because you may have up to 1040 concurrent calls in your code so you may very well be in a state with 1040 body opened and none yet closed.

You need to limit the number of goroutines used.

Here's one possible solution with a limit to 100 concurrent calls max :

```
func getThemAll() {
    nbConcurrentGet := 100
    urls :=  make(chan string, nbConcurrentGet)
    for i := 0; i < nbConcurrentGet; i++ {
        go func (){
            for url := range urls {
                get(url)
            }
        }()
    }
    for i:=0; i<1040; i++ {
        urls <- fmt.Sprintf("http://www.httpbin.org/get?a=%d", i)
    }
}
```

If you call this in the main function of your program, it may stop before all tasks are finished. You can use a `sync.WaitGroup` to prevent it :

```
func main() {
    nbConcurrentGet := 100
    urls :=  make(chan string, nbConcurrentGet)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < nbConcurrentGet; i++ {
        go func (){
            for url := range urls {
                get(url)
                wg.Done()
            }
        }()
    }
    for i:=0; i<1040; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        urls <- fmt.Sprintf("http://www.httpbin.org/get?a=%d", i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Finished")
}
```

Answer (score 16):

well technically your process is limited (by the Kernel) to about 1000 open file descriptors. Depending on the context you might need to increase this number.

In your shell run (note the last line):

```
$ ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)         unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)         unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)     unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)        8192
-c: core file size (blocks)    0
-v: address space (kb)         unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kb) unlimited
-u: processes                  709
-n: file descriptors           2560
```

To increase (temporarly):

```
$ ulimit -n 5000
(no output)
```

Then verify the fd limit:

```
$ ulimit -n
5000
```

Comment: my number is 1024, but why would there be over 1024 file descriptors exist? I have closed every one after they are handlered.

Comment: It is because when you use the `go` keyword the functions are run concurrently. You are fetching all 1040 urls at once using different connections. Because of this, you have 1040 (greater than 1024) FDs open at once.